# How would I select a var and update the value on ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to select a variable and then update the variable's value when my ajax call gets the new json but I can't figure out how to do that. Can someone explain to me how I would go about selecting the homePoints and awayPoints variables and replacing it with my updated value?

```
var homePoints = game.total_points_bet_on_hometeam;
var awayPoints = game.total_points_bet_on_awayteam;

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'doughnut',
              data: {
                labels: [homeTeam, awayTeam],
                datasets: [{
                  backgroundColor: [
                    hue,
                    hueTwo
                  ],
                  data: [homePoints, awayPoints]
                , borderWidth: 0
                }]
              },
              options: {
                    responsive: true
                ,   maintainAspectRatio: true
              }
            });
```

Comment: Use the `success` event handler on the ajax call.

Comment: @Unknown yes I do that already, but on success I'm wanting to replace those variables values.